# How to repopulate form data along with error after submitting form

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to display the form data after getting an error for the existing file after submitting the file. I want the error to be displayed along with the doc title which was previously typed in. For now, I'm able to display the error after submitting but the Title input is empty. I want the typed document title to stay. How to do that? I have added the code for doc.php and code.php below for reference. Hope this is useful to help me out.

```
    <?php
//check error
if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] !='')
{
    echo '<h2 class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"> '.$_SESSION['success'].'</h2> ';
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] !='')
{
    echo '<h2 class="bg-danger text-white"> '.$_SESSION['status'].'</h2> ';
    unset($_SESSION['status']);
}


?>
 <form action="code.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <hr style="border-top: 3px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">
  <h5>Add Documents</h5>
  <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">

  <div class="form-group" >
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc_title" class="form-control"  required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" >
      <label>Documents </label>
      <input type="file" name="doc" class="form-control" id="image"  required>
  </div>                
      
  <div class="float-right mb-2">        
    <button type="submit" name="adddoc" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <a href="doc.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>      
  </div>
 </form>
```

code.php

```
if(isset($_POST['adddoc']))
{
$docTitle=$_POST['doc_title'];

$file=$_FILES['doc'];

$doc_name=$_FILES['doc']['name'];
$doc_tmpName=$_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'];
$doc_size=$_FILES['doc']['size'];
$doc_error=$_FILES['doc']['error'];
$doc_type=$_FILES['doc']['type'];

$docExt=explode('.', $doc_name);
$docActualExt= strtolower(end($docExt));
$doc_allow=array('pdf','xlsx');

    if($doc_error === 0)
    {
        if($doc_size < 10000000)
        {

            $docDestination='upload/'.$doc_name;
            move_uploaded_file($doc_tmpName, $docDestination);

            $query="INSERT INTO documents (doc_title,doc) VALUES (?,?)";
            $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query)){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$docTitle,$doc_name);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
               
                $_SESSION['success']="Doc added";
            header('Location: doc.php');

            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['status']="Not added";
                header('Location: adddoc.php');

            }

        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['status']="The file is too big!";
            header('Location: adddoc.php');
          
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status']="Error uploading file";
            header('Location: adddoc.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of Error are you expecting? Are you planning to use AJAX? What have you tried so far? What is working and what is not? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you show code.php?

Comment: i have added more information. hope that's clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `$_POST['fieldName']` as an input value

```
<form action="code.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  

  <hr style="border-top: 3px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">

  <h5>Add Documents</h5>
  <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc_title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['doc_title']) ? $_POST['doc_title'] : '' ?>" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Documents </label>
      <input type="file" name="doc" class="form-control" id="image"  required>
  </div>                
      
  <div class="float-right mb-2">        
    <button type="submit" name="adddoc" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <a href="doc.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>      
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: That's not my question. I'm able to display the error message but the form is empty. how to keep the document title on place after submitting the form?

Comment: is this how i should write on the action?? :
      <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action=" code.php <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Comment: @Miracle1029 what's the point of changing? if you want it to post itself just don't write the action part